# Can't use go in Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: command-line, golang, visual-studio-code

I have the latest versions of Visual Studio Code and Go compiler. When I am trying to build file in Visual Studio Code terminal using `go build [FILENAME]` I get this output:
`The program 'go' can be found in the following packages:
* golang-go
* gccgo-go
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>`
But doing the same thing in separate terminal window works fine. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found solution for my problem. I forgot to add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` to `/etc/profile/`

Comment: It seems you did strange things. `/usr/local/` is for manually installed software. Why do not use [packaged system-wide versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=golang-go)? It is not Windows, you do not need to walk through all internet while searching MSI, EXE and MSP.